# beta/chats/:chatId/installedApps returns 404

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

According to documentation given here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/chat?view=graph-rest-beta#relationships

`GET  https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/chats/:chatId/installedApps` should return installed apps on that particular chat.

both `messages` and `members` endpoint on `chats` work as expected

But `installedApps` end point fails with 404 and response is

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json
request-id: 6a72dce1-52e5-4f50-84b7-4ce52f4e347d
client-request-id: 8db2cc88-3080-450f-8b3d-359222f74705
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"South India","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"3","ScaleUnit":"001","RoleInstance":"AGSFE_IN_7"}}
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: ETag, Location, Preference-Applied, Content-Range, request-id, client-request-id, ReadWriteConsistencyToken, SdkVersion
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Date: Tue, 21 Apr 2020 16:51:07 GMT
Content-Length: 198

{
  "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "6a72dce1-52e5-4f50-84b7-4ce52f4e347d",
      "date": "2020-04-21T16:51:07"
    }
  }
}
```

#### permission scopes are

```
Calendars.ReadWrite Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared Chat.ReadWrite Directory.Read.All Files.Read Files.Read.All Files.ReadWrite Group.ReadWrite.All Mail.Send MailboxSettings.Read Notes.ReadWrite.All openid profile Sites.ReadWrite.All Tasks.ReadWrite User.Read User.ReadBasic.All
```

Comment: Thanks for reporting this, We are looking into this.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct that apps can be installed and managed in a chat via the client (and therefore the relationship is correct), it is not supported by the Graph APIs (see documentation link below).

Currently, Graph supports installing apps only in team and user scope as listed in documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/teamsappinstallation?view=graph-rest-beta

Installing/Removing/Fetching/Updating apps in chat scope is not supported by Graph API at the moment

Comment: is support for chat specific app in graph is in roadmap or it will be never supported?

Comment: Yes, it is in roadmap, we will update once it is rolled out